# To comment code or not to comment code

Tags: comments

I have worked in various companies and in each place people have a different opinion on whether comments should be included in code.  Some say they shouldn't because the programmer's code should be simple enough to understand and should therefore be self-commenting.  They further contest that since code frequently changes and developers are not always diligent enough to update comments along with their code that comments quickly get out of date and therefore become misleading.  The other group say that the function of code is to describe, in technical terms what the system does, but that it doesn't always describe what the business reason for the code is and that therefore comments are useful in order to give context to the code.  I tend to lean towards the former point of view.  I was wondering what the views of the community are.  Please do share your thoughts.

Thanks,

Sachin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with you. The business reasons should be captured in acceptance tests, or, if your type system is powerful enough to express them, directly in the type system where they can be mechanically checked by the compiler.

Something as important as a business rule definitely does *not* belong in a comment, which is neither checked nor executed nor tested.